# Omitting the date when using \maketitle

Tags: titles, datetime

I'm using the `\author` and `\title` commands to produce a title with `\maketitle`. I also know that there is a `\date` command to specify the date of my work. However, if I omit `\date`, `\maketitle` will produce the current date. How do I achieve that no date is displayed at all?

```
\documentclass{article}

\author{Author, A.}
\title{Alpha}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Some text.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 402, accepted):

If you want a blank date, just use `\date{}`.

If you want to remove the spacing altogether where the date usually goes, look into using the [`titling`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titling) package, or else the mechanisms provided by your document class, depending on what it is.

Comment: If I use `\date{}` with the `article` class (instead of simply omitting the date), the vertical alignment of any following text will change as if the spacing was removed.

Comment: @lockstep long time post, but testing today (with TexStudio), the `\date{}` it works fine.

Comment: For future reference: if you want to use the `titling` package to remove space, you can do `\predate{}` and `\postdate{}` and then `\date{}` (as above). The same can be done for author (`\preauthor{}`, `\postauthor{}`, and `\author{}`) and title. To remove the space after the title line itself, do `\posttitle{\par\end{center}}`, which is the same as the default `posttitle` except with the `\vskip 0.5em` omitted (see `texdoc titling`, page 2).

Comment: Today the spacing seems to be gone already, so it should be fine.

Comment: This approach doesn't seem to work with KOMA. Specifically, the `scrartcl` class.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this information

Answer (score 210):

For a cheap and easy solution to removing the spacing without delving into the `titling` package that frabjous mentions, try:

```
\documentclass{article}

\author{Me}
\title{Foo}
\date{\vspace{-5ex}}
%\date{}  % Toggle commenting to test

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Bar

\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, also works for removing the author

Answer (score 32):

[@Reid](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3523/reid)’s `titling` solution (mentioned above in a comment, and alluded to in [@frabjous](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/411/frabjous)’s answer) deserves a full answer, since it does a nice job of removing the space associated with the date:

```
\documentclass{article}

% remove spacing around date:
\usepackage{titling}
\predate{}
\postdate{}

\author{Author, A.}
\title{Alpha}
\date{} % clear date

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Some text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain how this works? What do `\predate{}` and `\postdate{}` do?

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer They remove the spacing around the date by setting pre- and post-date hooks (provided by `titling` package) to empty.

Comment: This works well in Lyx's preamble for an article.

Answer (score 9):

**Important: ordering matters when using `\date{}`**

In *Overleaf*, date omission only works if `\date{}` comes **before** `\maketitle`. Minimal Working Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\title{Some title}
\date{}
\maketitle
%% \date{} % omission fails if placed after maketitle instead
\end{document}
```

Comment: In general, `\date` will always only then have an effect on `\maketitle` if it comes before `\maketitle`. And this is not only the case in Overleaf (which just uses a normal TeX distribution anyways).