# Omit the date in \maketitle *without blanking the date*

Tags: titles, koma-script

So, this is building on [Omitting the date when using `\maketitle`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2760/omitting-the-date-when-using-maketitle); but I'd still like to include the date *in the page footer*. This means `\date{}` isn't an option. (Of course, I'd like to get rid of the superfluous spacing in `\maketitle` as well.)

I'm using KOMA (specifically, `scrartcl`); but I couldn't hunt down a built-in way to disable this; does that exist? If not, can I use the `{titling}` package to do this?

```
\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[subsection]{section}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\title{Something}
\author{Some Body}

\ofoot{\today}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
   \maketitle
   \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) so we don't have to construct one from scratch (regardless of how simple it may seem to you to do such a thing). Additionally, could you be specific about what you mean by "superfluous spacing in `\maketitle`"? Spacing above and below? how much do you want that to change?

Comment: Will do! The original post mentions that `\date{}` removes the line, but leaves invisible spacing that had been placed *around* it. [This comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2760/omitting-the-date-when-using-maketitle#comment371253_2761) by [Reid](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3523/reid) demonstrates one way to remove the spacing (but that still wipes out the *actual `\date{}`*.)

Comment: I don't get it. The date is still included in the footer if you add `\date{}`, adding that doesn't change `\today`.

Comment: Oh. Hmmmm. In my original document, `\today` was evaluating to the numeral `0`, so I assumed `\date{}` was resetting the date globally or something. Must be some un-related issue, I'll go digging … thank you! >,<

Comment: That's precisely why you make a minimal example to post here. Or just for troubleshooting. (Minimal examples are not a side-effect of sites like this.)

Comment: You could do the title by hand. I don't know if your title really is as simple as shown, but creating your own might be easier and faster than digging for a solution for customizing a predefined setting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you only wish to remove the `\date`-related entry in the title, then you can patch `\@maketitle` and remove the relevant content (using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage,etoolbox}
\automark[subsection]{section}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\title{Something}
\author{Some Body}

\ofoot{\today}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
% Remove \@date and spacing following it from \@maketitle
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}% <cmd>
  {{\usekomafont{date}{\@date \par}}%
    \vskip \z@ \@plus 1em}% <search>
  {}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

The above

```
\patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
```

searches for `<search>` in `<cmd>` and replaces it with `<replace>` (executing `<success>` on success of the patch, or `<failure>` otherwise). Since we're patching `\@maketitle`, let's look at its definition (in [`scrkernel-title.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/source/scrkernel-title.dtx)):

```
\newcommand*{\@maketitle}{%
  \global\@topnum=\z@
  \ifx\@titlehead\@empty \else
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
      \usekomafont{titlehead}{\@titlehead\par}%
    \end{minipage}\par
  \fi
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
    \ifx\@subject\@empty \else
      {\usekomafont{subject}{\@subject \par}}%
      \vskip 1.5em
    \fi
    {\usekomafont{title}{\huge \@title \par}}%
    \vskip .5em
    {\ifx\@subtitle\@empty\else\usekomafont{subtitle}\@subtitle\par\fi}%
    \vskip 1em
    {%
      \usekomafont{author}{%
        \lineskip .5em%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
          \@author
        \end{tabular}\par
      }%
    }%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\usekomafont{date}{\@date \par}}%
    \vskip \z@ \@plus 1em
    {\usekomafont{publishers}{\@publishers \par}}%
    \ifx\@dedication\@empty \else
      \vskip 2em
      {\usekomafont{dedication}{\@dedication \par}}%
    \fi
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 2em
}%
```

The occurrence of

```
    {\usekomafont{date}{\@date \par}}%
    \vskip \z@ \@plus 1em
```

is replaced with with nothing (removed), since `<replace>` is empty. As such, no `\@date` is set, and neither is the usual `\vskip` space following it.

Comment: This is great! A little more exposition on *what* you're doing inside that patch might be good, but otherwise … accepted! <3

Comment: @ELLIOTTCABLE: See my updated answer where I explain a little what the `\patchcmd` does.

Comment: Beaaaautiful! :D

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this might work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[L]{\today\ -Page \thepage}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\author{Me}
\title{Foo}
\date{\vspace{-5ex}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\pagenumbering{gobble}  
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}      
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: That answer is *mildly* non-compatible to the class the OP is using.