# How to Suppress the Date Generated by Maketitle

Tags: titles, document-classes, books, book-design, date

Consider the code:

```
\documentclass[titlepage,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=.3in,paperwidth=4in,paperheight=6in]{geometry}
\textheight=5.25in
\usepackage[frame,noinfo,center]{crop}
\usepackage{microtype,scalefnt}

\title{TITLE\\[-4pt] {\scalefont{0.45}{{\textit{OF THE}}}}\\[3pt] BOOK}
%\author{The Author}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

which produces the page

[image]

QUESTION: How may I prevent `\maketitle` from displaying the date?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try `\date{}` ? This technically won't suppress it, just replace it with an empty one.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Just did. Many thanks.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Ah! I did not see that before posting the question. I had guessed the question was asked before but I didn't see it.

Comment: No worries, your question will be a helpful signpost for future users with the same problem, so they can find the linked post more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the default date with an empty one:

```
\documentclass[titlepage,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=.3in,paperwidth=4in,paperheight=6in]{geometry}
\textheight=5.25in
\usepackage[frame,noinfo,center]{crop}
\usepackage{microtype,scalefnt}

\title{TITLE\\[-4pt] {\scalefont{0.45}{{\textit{OF THE}}}}\\[3pt] BOOK}
%\author{The Author}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks again. The system is making me wait to accept the answer.

Comment: @mlchristians Better plan: I think I found a suitable duplicate. Have a look if we can link your question to this dupe: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2760/omitting-the-date-when-using-maketitle

Comment: That's fine with me.